# jQuery validation: show error message in input field?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm currently using the jQuery validation script (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate my form inputs. However, I don't like that the error messages are displayed next my input elements. I'd rather display them INSIDE my input elements, as placeholders.

That means that when, for example, a field is left empty, the error message "This field is required." is not displayed next to the input element in an "error" class, but as a placeholder inside the input element.

I can't seem to figure out how to make this work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Code would be good but that will likely involve either writing your own validation or you could edit the jQuery validation code

Answer (score 0):

When placeholders aren't supported you usually use a label with position absolute to overlay the input and hide onfocus. The same logic can be applied to error messages whilst maintaining accessibility and not relying on the placeholder attribute. The div enclosing should be inline so the error text is kept inline with the input width.

```
<div style="position:relative;display:inline;">
  <input type="text">
  <span style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">My error message</span>
</div>
```